# PHP echo html hidden input value (before form is sent)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two hidden fields with values containing the **name** and **id** of a user ("touserid" and "tousername"). In the same form I want to echo "Write **(the user)** a message". So in this echo message I must retrieve the username from the hidden field name. Is that possible?

This is the form (popup div) for sending message to a chosen user:

```
<div id="overlay_mess">                                                                     <!--  mess = send message   -->
    <div id="popupdiv_mess">         <!-- popup: send message to chosen friend-->
        <form action="/22feb_community/message/postmessage" method="post">
            <?php echo "Write " .  "a message." ?><br><br>
            <textarea name="messagetext"></textarea><br><br>
            <span>Private: <input type="radio" name="visibility" value="1"> Public: <input type="radio" name="visibility" value="2"></span><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="touserid" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="tousername" value="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_message" value="Send"><br>
        </form>
        <a href='#' onclick='overlay_mess()'>close </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

To explain the background: This is a user page where the user's friends are displayed by php. On each friend the user can click "send message", which shows a popup-div with a form for sending a message to this user. I had to create data attributes for each friend containing the id and name, and let javascript retrieve and put them into the hidden fields of the form. But the id and name is only available in these hidden fields. Besides the main question, are there better ways to do this?

edit:
javascript:

```
    $('.friend').on('click',function(){
        var dAttribute1 = $(this).closest("div").attr("data-userid");   //take clicked user's userid
        var dAttribute2 = $(this).closest("div").attr("data-username");  //take username
        $("input[name='touserid']").val(dAttribute1);               //put user id in hidden inputfield
        $("input[name='tousername']").val(dAttribute2);         //username in hidden inputfield

        var el = document.getElementById("overlay_mess");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="touserid" value="<?php echo $var; ?>">`

Comment: So, where are we at? Solved? ^ ^ ^ or is this question still open?

Comment: The value is set by javascript. Will it automatically be set to that php variable?

Comment: If you're already getting one from it, sure... why not? Try it and look at the HTML source to see it.

Comment: It didn't work. "Undefined variable: var "
This is the line:

    <input type="hidden" name="tousername" value="<?php echo $var; ?>">    

and console log shows that the value is set to the username.
console.log((document.querySelector("input[name='tousername']").value));

Comment: That was an example. You'll need to assign that to what you wish to assign it to. I.e.: `$var=$_POST['variable'];` or whatever it is you want it to be and where/how it's being pulled in from. `$var="Said user";` - and using `isset()` in your PHP against the POST array.

Comment: If I set $var = "" there is no error but it is not being set to the username. It is an empty string. But the value is set to the username.

Comment: I need to know where the username(s) is/are coming from/pulled in from. It's not shown in your question/code.